# IE ignores octet-stream - how to force download?

Tags: pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to generate PDF files. This program accepts one of two ContentType values, 'application/pdf' and 'application/octet-stream'. I want the PDF files generated to be saved to the user's machine, so I set it to 'application/octet-stream'. Chrome prompted the download, just as expected. So did FireFox. Of course Internet Explorer ignored this setting and opened the PDF file in a browser window instead. I'm using Internet Explorer 8 and 9 for testing this. I don't have access to the server, and I don't want to change how all PDF files are handled in any case. I want this application to prompt the user to download the file, and need to know how to force IE to do this instead of ignoring the ContentType value.

I used Fiddler2 to check out how the ContentType is being reported in IE and Chrome, and both show 'application/octet-stream', so I'm not sure why IE is insisting on rendering the PDF in a browser. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

PHP CODE:

```
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"filename\"");
```

This should work.

Comment: Content-Disposition as 'attachment' did the trick for me in conjunction with the octet-stream mime type.  The other settings made my browsers shrug their shoulders.  Thanks for the post. +1